# how i know whitch virtualhost use more ressources on my apache webserver ?

Tags: apache

I have a ubuntu web server with apache. sometimes the load reach 10 . do you have tips to identify which virtual host use more apache ?

thank you a lot

Comment: what is "the load" for you? load average of the OS or number of apache childs? tell us more things if you want an accurate answer.

Comment: having a load average reaching 10 is not a problem by itself, it simply means your computer is working, which is the meaning of life for computers. Do you have some slow responses? Do you only have apache on this server? no database? how much virtualhosts, which mpm for apache, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Check Apache server-status:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_status.html

Use it with "ExtendedStatus On" and you have a list of processes pr virtual host.

Example:

http://www.apache.org/server-status